# react is trying to render the page even before the params.id is being fetched so only the if statement is being running every time

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-native

I want to render the react code when the id in the params match the id in the data but here react tries to render the code even before `props.match.params.id` is being executed so only the if statement is being executed can you provide me with a solution to solve this.Ive even tried using `useParams()` but it does not do anything good.

```
import data from'./data'
import React  from 'react'



export default function Productdisplay(props) {
 
  const y= props.match.params.id
  const product=data.products.find((x) => x.id===y); //An error lies here

  if(!product){
    return(
      <div>No product to display {}</div>
    )
  }
return(
<>
//Here lies the code I want to render when the ids of the url and data  match 
but as React tries to render the code even before the params is being fetched 
only if statement is being rendered can you give me a solution for this
</>
)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to use here is a useEffect that contains your conditions/logic that will run when its depecencies change. Here it is *Y*.
Then store the ouput of your logic from the useEffect into a real state (useState) and not a const. From there you'll be able to trigger the re-render you expect.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function Productdisplay(props) {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    const y = props ? .match ? .params ? .id;
    const findProducts = data.products.find((x) => x.id === y);

    if (findProducts !== products) {
      setProducts(products);
    }
  }, [data?.products, props?.match?.params?.id]);

  if(!products) return null; 
  return (
    <div>
      // ...
    </div>
  );
```

I suggest you to read this https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

Comment: could you please use useeffect and usestate in my code as iam new to react i am not able to do it

Comment: Look at my edited answer

Comment: Thanks for your time but i still have the same error